# Archiving a lot of files / one big file

Tags: backup, tar, compression, gzip

I want to compress about 100'000 files (that's what `find . -type f | wc -l` says) with a total disk usage of 100 GB. Most of the files are small but just a handful of them makes up about 70 GB of the 100 GB.

I don't want to use tar or tar.gz for this because if I want to access the archive, File Roller first has to read in the entire archive from the external HDD before I can even see the file list. Same thing if I try to list the files on the terminal.

I don't need the rights management of tar because I can remember the few files which need other rights than the others. What compression algorithm should I use?

And while I'm at it: I make full disk backups with this command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=32M | gzip -9 > /location/dateAndMachineName.gz
```

It does a pretty good compression. But do you know a better compression algorithm?

Comment: Use `lzma` or `xz`.

Comment: @muru in combination with tar or not? Using it in combination with tar will result in just the same issue, or will it?

Comment: They're tools just like `gzip`, but different algorithms. Whatever reasoning you applied to arrive at using `gzip` would apply to them too.

Comment: @mure Then why would I use either `lzma` or `xz` instead of `gz`?

Comment: Doesn't your question say "But do you know a better compression algorithm?"

Comment: @muru Oh, you're talking about the backup command. I thought you're talking about the initial question. Thank you for your answer, however, their throughput on encrypted / random data is way to low (at least on my machine). None of them work without tar which leaves me with the original problem.

Comment: Care to try SquashFS? It's a compressed, read-only filesystem that you can mount to see the contents directly. You'll see it used on Ubuntu live CDs, for example. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html

Answer (score 5):

The only solution I am aware of is **[pixz](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) (`sudo apt-get install pixz`)**, a variant of xz using a blocked encoder which allows for fast random acccess/indexing. Additionally, it is a parallel method using multiple cores for compression.

Citing the docs:

> The existing XZ Utils ( http://tukaani.org/xz/ ) provide great
>   compression in the .xz file format, but they have two significant
>   problems:
>
> - They are single-threaded, while most users nowadays have multi-core computers.
> - The .xz files they produce are just one big block of compressed data, rather than a collection of smaller blocks. This makes random
>     access to the original data impossible.
>
> With pixz, both these problems are solved.

Usage is simple:

`tar -Ipixz -cf foo.tpxz foo` to compress a folder `foo`

`pixz -l foo.tpxz` to list files in it (fast!)

`pixz -x <file_path> < foo.tpxz | tar x` to extract a single file given `<file_path>` in the archive

As a bonus, you will get access rights stored as well since the files are tarred first!

Answer (score 1):

I con only think of one solution for you:
Make a new partition, with a btrfs filesystem and activate transparent compression.
Keep in mind tha some people still considder btrfs an "experimental" filesystem. That being said, my secondary backup HDD is using btrfs (for little over 2 years) and so far it's given me 0 issues. But as usual YMMV.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs) and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs) should get you started with btrfs, if you are not familiar with it already.

Comment: +1: Your solution look for me highly interesting (in fact I'm sure that the OP will be also interested) Hower, would be a **very** good answer *if** you include a step-by-step procedure. Link-only answers are not welcome.

Comment: I know about link answers, but for a step by step procedure I would need to know more about the OP's setup, such as HDDs, current partitions, etc, which I bealive is a bit out of scope...

Comment: Ok, sorry. I understood your viewpoint. **:-/**